# $F(x,y,z)=0$ differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Suppose $F:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is $C^1$, and $F(x,y,z)=0$. $z = f (x, y), x = g(y, z)$, and $y = h(x,z)$.

Show that $\frac{\partial z~\partial x~\partial y}{\partial x ~\partial y~\partial z}=-1$.

I know for $f(x,y)=0$, we get $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{df}{dy}}$.

Comment: I tried to use this result from $f(x,y)=0$, but then I find difficulty saying $f(x,y)=0$ given $F(x,y,z)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate the equation $F(x,y,f(x,y))= 0$ with respect to $x$ to get 
\begin{equation*}
 F_x + F_z\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0.
\end{equation*}
Differentiate the equation $F(x, h(x,z), z) = 0$ to with respect to $z$ to get
\begin{equation*}
 F_y\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} + F_z=0. 
\end{equation*} 
Differentiate the equation $F(g(y,z), y, z)= 0$ to wth respect to $y$ to get
\begin{equation*}
 F_x\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + F_y = 0. 
\end{equation*}
Using the three computations above gives
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \left(-\frac{F_x}{F_z}\right)\left(-\frac{F_y}{F_x}\right)\left(- \frac{F_z}{F_y}\right)= 
-1. 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you, but I did not get why you get $F_x+F_z\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$. Could you please elaborate how you differentiate that?

Comment: The chain rule says $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x,y,z) = F_x\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} +F_y\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + F_z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. Now use the relations $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$ and, since $z = f(x,y)$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.